# List Variables and Methods on DOM Object

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web-component

How would I find out what variables and methods are on a DOM Object? In the example below, how do I find out that `div#main` has a variable `greeting`, and a method `greet`?

(Preferably without using an external library.)

```js
var main = document.querySelector('#main');

main.greeting = 'Hello Meep!';

main.greet = function() {
  alert(this.greeting);
}

main.greet();
```

```html
<div id="main">
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On browsers that allow it with DOM elements, you can use `Object.keys` or `for-in` to get an array of the enumerable properties:

```
console.log(Object.keys(main));
```

That works on a wide range of modern browsers, but note that browsers are not **required** to allow you to introspect DOM elements that way, so if you rely on it, be sure to test in your target browsers.

If you want non-enumerable properties as well as enumerable ones, you could try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(main)` rather than `Object.keys(main)`.

**Example**:

```js
var main = document.querySelector('#main');

main.greeting = 'Hello Meep!';

main.greet = function() {
  alert(this.greeting);
}

main.greet();

var p = document.createElement('p');
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
  Object.keys(main).join(", ")
));
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

```html
<div id="main">
  ...
</div>
```